# How to reference a service in a non-service class?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, declarative-services

As the title suggests, I would like to reference a service in a non-service class, the way I can think of is as follows :

```java
@Component( immediate = true )
public class Foo {
    
    @Reference
    private Bar bar ;
    
}
```

But `Foo` seems to be instantiated and references `bar` when the plugin it's in starts up, if I `new Foo()`, `bar` is null.

Is there any way to make `Foo` not instantiate automatically, but rather I can `new` it myself and make `bar` not null ?

In other words, must the `Component` be created when the plugin starts ?

Comment: Have you read something like the Vogella tutorial - https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html ? My understanding is that `immediate=true` starts the service as soon as possible which is not what you want here. You can't use `new` as that doesn't do any sort of injection. The Vogella tutorial talks about getting services from the bundle context or using ServiceTracker.

Comment: Yes, I know I can use the bundle context or ServiceTracker or annotate the `bar` with `@Inject` and then get the service via `ContextInjectionFactory.inject( new Foo(), context )`. I'm new to DS and I'm looking into it, and I was wondering if I could use `@Reference` to get the service in a similar way to `ContextInjectionFactory.inject()`, but it doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

Use the newest DS spec from OSGi R7 or R8. It allows constructor injection of services. This way you can inject the service also when doing new.